# puppet create certificate with fqdn

Tags: linux, centos, puppet

`hostname` on the client is `dns01.srv.acentauri.net.uk`, however when I run

```
puppet agent -t

Info: Creating a new SSL key for dns01
Info: Caching certificate for ca
Info: Caching certificate_request for dns01
Exiting; no certificate found and waitforcert is disabled
```

it creates certificate for host `dns01`, appearently I am using `autosign` on puppet master for this domain `srv.acentauri.net.uk`

Any idea why puppet does not create the SSL key for FQDN?

Answer (score 2):

Check the FQDN of your host:

```
# hostname -f
# domainname
```

Check also for a valid entry in your `/etc/hosts` file:

```
1.2.3.4  dns01.srv.acentauri.net.uk dsn01
```

Additionally, set the `HOSTNAME` entry in `/etc/sysconfig/network` to the FQDN.

Remove the invalid cryptographic content under `/var/lib/puppet/ssl` in the client machine:

```
# rm -rf /var/lib/puppet/ssl
```

and reissue the request, this time waiting for the answer:

```
# puppet agent --test --waitforcert 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The client machine probably has an entry for `dns01` in `/etc/hosts`. Have a look at what `hostname -f` and `hostname -i` return and clean up any discrepancies.